# ProgressBar setVisibility doesn't show at the right time

Tags: android, visibility

```
public void generateNumbers(){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    while(){
        //approximately 5 second long procedure
    }
    printNumbers();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

I want that the progress bar is visible when this long procedure in while loop is running and then dissapear. The code like this shown progressBar after the loop is finished and then also dissapear (setVisiblity(GONE)).

In while loop i don't have any new threads or AsyncTask

Comment: So what is your problem here?

Comment: Problem is that progress bar become visible after long loop and not before like i want

Comment: `In while loop i don't have any new threads or AsyncTask` <= that's why ... i assume that you are calling `generateNumbers()` from UI thread (maybe some onClick) so any other calls that using UI thread are blocked until `generateNumbers()` is finished

Comment: use `AsyncTask` ... show progressBar in `onPreExecute()` do loop in `doInBackground(...)` and hide progressBar in `onPostExecute(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Use an asynctask like this

```
    public class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Context context;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public asyncTask(Context cxt) {
            context = cxt;

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }



        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            dialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
            dialog.show();



        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            //Put your code here 
             }

}
```